# Mail sending using Spring4 and Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to send a simple HTML mail using Spring 4 and Thymeleaf templates. In my java class I have:

```
public void sendMail() throws Exception {
    if (!flag){
        throw new IOException("Mail Sending Forbiden");
    }

    // Prepare the evaluation context
    final Context ctx = new Context();
    List<FacebookFeed> list = getFeedsList();
    ctx.setVariable("message", "message");
    //Prepare message using a Spring helper
    final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    final MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "UTF-8");
    message.setSubject("Example HTML email (simple)");
    message.setTo(recipient);

    // Create the HTML body using Thymeleaf
    final String htmlContent = this.htmlTemplateEngine.process("/static/test", ctx);
    System.out.println(htmlContent);
    message.setText(htmlContent, true /* isHtml */);

    // Send email
    this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
}
```

And I'm using thymeleaf th:text in my html page:

```
<span th:text="${message}"></span>
```

But it doesn't work. All that I get in my template is the same .html page.
`th:text="${message}"` - doesn't work

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you create `htmlTemplateEngine`? Is the property `spring.thymeleaf.suffix` set to `html`?

Comment: Anyhow, if you can switch to Spring Boot I recommend to use this library: [Email Tools](https://github.com/ozimov/spring-boot-email-tools)

Comment: As far as I know, the `htmlTemplateEngine` should be an instance of `org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine`, that you should be able to autowire in your class. If this is correct, I would just jump into the `process` method and debug until I don't see why the context is not used

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was:

```
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.TEXT);
```

instead of

```
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
```

Comment: And please, let us know where this `templateResolver` comes from? This was not mentioned at all in the question